# How do I contact a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

I was wondering how do I contact the moderators on Stack Exchange and how do I figure out who they are? How do I contact them privately?

Answer (score 11):

> how do I figure out who they are?

The Users section of every site has a moderators sub tab.

> how do I contact the moderators

Diamond moderators (elected or pro tempore - these are the people listed in the moderators tab) can be contacted by flagging a post or comment using the "Other" flag reason.

If you want to contact the Community Team (who are Stack Exchange employees), use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link on the footer.

> How do I contact them privately?

See the above. Those are the established mechanisms to contacting the moderators. These are not public mechanisms, though they are visible to all moderators of the site they are on and to the community team.

Answer (score 6):

The moderators for Stack Overflow are listed here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

but you don't contact them privately. This page exists for all sites - except this one.

If you want to raise something flag one of your posts or ask a question on [Stack Overflow's Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). The same approach works here as the community managers are the moderators for this site.

If it's something we can't deal with then use the contact us form linked at the foot of every page to send an e-mail to the community managers.

Answer (score 5):

For any site, you can visit the `/users?tab=moderators` page. For example, SO's moderators are on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

To contact a moderator to inform them of content that requires their attention, you'll need 15 reputation to flag a post. When you get 15 rep, a flag link will appear that allows you to choose from a number of reasons or write your own.